# C code produces different results on OS X vs Linux

Tags: c, linux, macos

I'm attempting to execute the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a = 5;
int fun1(){
  a = 17;
  return 3;
}

int main(){
  int b;
  b = a + fun1();
  printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

When I run it on my macbook I get an answer of 8, but when I run it in Linux I get an answer of 20. I've had a few friends run it and everyone with a Mac gets 8, while everyone running Linux gets 20. What would cause this?

I'm not so much interested in the correct answer as I am on the reason behind the two environments giving different answers. What about OS X and Linux causes the discrepancy?

Comment: first of all - you cannot execute c code, you can compile into binary and then run, so, difference not between linux/osx, but between different compilers

Comment: A technicality, but you are correct none the less. OS X uses LLVM, while those on Linux were using gcc. I compiled using the command gcc sample.c -o sample on OS X.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Calling and returning from a function are sequence points. The problem is order of evaluation, not sequence points, as explained in the answers.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Not undefined behaviour. Just unspecified behaviour. Exactly one of two behaviours is guaranteed to happen.

Comment: @Barmar, gnasher729 You are right.

Comment: its a nice case of 'well behaved' undefined behavior. Ie there are 2 distinct possible outcomes (in practice not theory) and the 2 compilers have interestingly chosen one each. Interesting to investigate why - I mean is it accidental, deliberate, a natural outcome of the compiler architectures...

Comment: @pm100 I guess it is natural consequence of a deliberate design consideration.

Answer (score 9):

The order of evaluation of parameters to operator `+` is unspecified. That means that there is no particular ordering, and `fun1()` can be evaluated before or after the read of `a` in the expression `a + fun1()`<sup>*</sup>. You are seeing the effect of different orders of evaluation on different platforms.

---

<sup>* Note that the function call `fun1()` introduces a sequence point, so the behaviour of `a + fun1();` is well defined, even if the order of evaluation of the operands is *unspecified*. Without a function call there would be no sequence point (e.g. `a + a++`), which would yield *undefined behaviour*.</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The order in which operands are evaluated is unspecified. That means in the expression a + fun1 () the compiler can choose to evaluate a before or after calling fun1 (). Both results are correct. Your code isn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specification for how to evaluate these operands, so the compiler may choose either order. It seems in this case that the compiler you use on your Mac has a different implementation for evaluation order than the compiler on your Linux, thus the apparent inconsistency. Writing cleaner code greatly helps for things like this.